# What exactly does stand IKB for?

Tags: boolean, byte

I have a question which goes as:

**IKB** is equal to:

(a) 1k bytes (b) 1024 bytes (c) 210 bytes (d) none of these

The answer says (b), but I haven't heard of this before, so my question is what exactly is IKB?

Comment: I question paper says **IKB**, I just rechecked.

Comment: I think that should be a 1, otherwise this would not make a lot of sense

Comment: That's weird because the answers indicate 1 instead of I

Comment: The answers are assuming the question has a typo.

Comment: `IKB` seems to be a typo of `KiB`, which means kibibyte. [1 kibibyte = 1024 bytes](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#1KiB).

Answer (score 6):

[image]

with thanks to [Kilobyte](http://xkcd.com/394/)

If you do a quick google, you will find a lot of explanations,

something like [Bits and Bytes : An Explanation](http://www.help2go.com/Tutorials/Computer_Basics/Bits_and_Bytes_:_An_Explanation.html)

Comment: Uncle Fester - I wish I could give you MORE than just +1.  Lots more!

Comment: I would probably rather ask one of the exameners to verify if it is "IKB, lKB or 1KB" to ensure you dont miss some easy marks

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly supposed to read “1KB” or 1 kilobyte, which is usually taken to mean 1024 bytes rather 1000 bytes.

Comment: StackOverflow tags are pretty complete and yet when you type in IKB as a tag you get nothing.  Kinda supports the 1 over I answer

Answer (score 0):

"1kb" == "1 kilobyte" == 1024 bytes

"IKB" doesn't mean any of these things.

So I guess "d)" is the answer.

Can you say "Trick Question"? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
kilobyte (kB)   10^3        kibibyte (KiB)  2^10 = 1.024 × 103
megabyte (MB)   10^6        mebibyte (MiB)  2^20 ≈ 1.049 × 106
gigabyte (GB)   10^9        gibibyte (GiB)  2^30 ≈ 1.074 × 109
terabyte (TB)   10^12       tebibyte (TiB)  2^40 ≈ 1.100 × 1012
petabyte (PB)   10^15       pebibyte (PiB)  2^50 ≈ 1.126 × 1015
exabyte (EB)    10^18       exbibyte (EiB)  2^60 ≈ 1.153 × 1018
zettabyte (ZB)  10^21       zebibyte (ZiB)  2^70 ≈ 1.181 × 1021
yottabyte (YB)  10^24       yobibyte (YiB)  2^80 ≈ 1.209 × 102
```

This is all SI decimal prefixes(left)and EC binary prefixes(right)

as you can see not one of them used "lkb" so it must be a typo

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Comment: I hope they adopt the proposal for the "hella" prefix. I just want the opportunity to talk about "hellabytes".

Comment: That may be the standard, but very few use it. Everyone in ECE means 1024 bytes when they say 1KB, and 1024KB when they say 1MB. It's as if that standard was written by disk drive manufacturers.